# Does the Quran urge persecution of the infidel?

Tags: quran

There is much misinformation revolving around the violent persons in the middle east who claim to be Islam and some even claim that they are doing what Allah wants.

Can their actions be justified by what is written in the Quran? Are there parts in the Quran that urge the Muslim to hurt, cheat, lie to, steal from or otherwise persecute the non-Muslim? In the least, are there parts that say it is okay to do those things to an infidel, but it is not required

If not then can their actions be condemned by what is written in the Quran?

**Edit:** **I have been given a few answers in the comments but no answers with any quotes. It would be nice to see the text of the Quran people are referring to.**

Comment: No. It does not. Can you bring the verses that you think are used by those people to justify their actions? Islam urges people to fulfill one's trust, speak the truth even if others don't like it, and to protect the one who seeks asylum (even if he is non-muslim).

Comment: @Abdullah I have no verses. Just misinformation from people who likely do not know and only wish to villainize people they do not like. I here things like this on TV, in emails, and the loud mouths at parties. Perhaps you can give the verses you are talking about?

Comment: Islam does not urges persecution of infidels but urges to fight them only at the time of war. The second case is it urges to fight them in case of getting Jazya (tax on non Muslims). Other than that there is no persecution on non Muslims. They are treated exactly as Muslim. Their laws are respected.

Comment: @TheTruthSeaker When is a time of war, then? Do not these same violent people say that they are at war? Is that how they justify it? What does the Quran say about war then? So Jazya is a tax on non-Muslims. When can that be placed? But does the Quran say anything like "Don't steal, but it's okay to steal from the Infidel?" Does it have a list of moral laws like the Christian Bible has the ten commandments?

Comment: @fredsbend the time of War is the actual war when the leader declares war. But these verse are not very clear, they do not explicitly mention ' in the time of war' etc. It is simply believed that these verse are for War only and for that time only. Nevertheless some Muslim do take it literally because of ignorance. But that case is very rare. Generally a non Muslim will never ever be prosecuted by Muslim, except he insults the prophet. He has full rights to practice his own religion.

Comment: Dear fredsbend.... this article is especially for you... Hope it satisfies you....  [Your Modern Islam](http://yourmodernislam.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 3):

There are many verses in the Quran that prohibit killing of any human.

### Quran:

> Say, "Come, I will recite what your Lord has prohibited to you. [He commands] that you not associate anything with Him, and to parents, good treatment, and do not kill your children out of poverty; We will provide for you and them. And do not approach immoralities - what is apparent of them and what is concealed. **And do not kill the soul which Allah has forbidden [to be killed] except by [legal] right**. This has He instructed you that you may use reason." [An-Nam verse 151](http://quran.com/6/151)

### Hadith:

> Narrated `Abdullah bin`Amr:
>   The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Whoever killed a Mu'ahid (a person who is granted the pledge of protection by the Muslims) shall not smell the fragrance of Paradise though its fragrance can be smelt at a distance of forty years (of traveling). [Bukhary - sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/87/52)

Ignore the history or what people are doing in the middle east for now. If someone claims to be a muslim. They he/she should never ignore these two. Muslim's goal is to enter paradise. Killing a human without any reason contradicts everything a muslims belief in.

Comment: The versed you cited obviously do not prohibit killing of **ANY** human. It is not clear from your answer whether or not "[legal] right" extends to infidels (who are often seen by muslims as enemies of Islam).

Answer (score 3):

No, persecution of non Muslims is not allowed. Prophet (s.a) even said,

> أَنَسَ بْنَ مَالِكٍ يَقُولُ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ
> عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ اتَّقُوا دَعْوَةَ الْمَظْلُومِ وَإِنْ كَانَ
> كَافِرًا فَإِنَّهُ لَيْسَ دُونَهَا حِجَابٌ
>
> “Beware of the supplication of the oppressed, even if he is an
> unbeliever, for there is no screen between it and Allah.” Saheeh
> Hadith in Musnad Ahmad 12140 [About authenticity of this hadith (Arabic)](https://mawdoo3.com/%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%AC_%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AB_(%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%82%D9%88%D8%A7_%D8%AF%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B8%D9%84%D9%88%D9%85_%D9%88%D9%84%D9%88_%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%86_%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%A7))

This means persecuted person's prayer will be readily heard by God, even if the persecuted person is non believer.

Of course, there are Muslims that claim persecution of non Muslims is ok. They say the verses of tolerance and religious freedom in Quran are no longer valid because of verses revealed during self defensive war of Islam. Actually, there is no truth in it. Muslims are to follow Quran fully and cannot set aside verses, Quran itself gives warning to those who does this.

> So do you believe in part of the Scripture and disbelieve in part?
> Then what is the recompense for those who do that among you except
> disgrace in worldly life; and on the Day of Resurrection they will be
> sent back to the severest of punishment. And Allah is not unaware of
> what you do." [Quran 2:85](http://quran.com/2/85)

see also these answers

- [Are muslims supposed to kill all non-believers?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14595/are-muslims-supposed-to-kill-all-non-believers/14601#14601)
- [Intolerance in muslims](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17080/intolerance-in-muslims/20240#20240)

Answer (score 0):

Historically, non-Muslims were under the protection of Muslim nations in early Islam, and the Jizya tax was less than standard taxes neighboring countries.

See:

- [Constitution of Medina](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_Medina#Rights_of_non-Muslims)
- [Treatment of non-Muslims during the Rashidun Caliphate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashidun_Caliphate#Treatment_of_Conquered_Peoples).

Many of the "Islamic" nations after the Rashidun Caliphate did persecute non-Muslims, but how can it be Islamic if the Prophet and those who followed him most closely didn't do it?

However, the kind treatment of non-Muslims often extended only to dhimmis. "Dhimmi" was originally considered People of the Book ([Wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhimmi)), i.e. Jews, Christians, other monotheists who worshipped the same God. Other Islamic rulers later extended this term to mean Hindus, Buddhists, and all non-Muslims.

I've read somewhere that non-dhimmi non-Muslims had to be persecuted and not given freedom of religion, hence why Muslim leaders were eager to consider all non-Muslims as dhimmis. But can't find the source for this yet.

Comment: Excellent answer. I would love to see the sources for that.

Comment: Is the Medina constitution not now widely disavowed?

Comment: @Gracchus Why would it be disavowed?

Comment: @Ansari Wikipedia used to have a laundry list of refutations against its authenticity, but they all seem to be gone now.  Nevermind.

Comment: Jizya can be collected from polytheists, see this saheeh hadith http://sunnah.com/muslim/32/3 . it is not right to compel anyone to Islam, it is against Quran 2:256, 10:99

Answer (score -4):

Read the first ten Ayah in surah Tauwbeh in this [link](http://quranexplorer.com/index/Sura_009_Al_Tawba_REPENTANCE_DISPENSATION.aspx) and I hope you get at least an answer which solve 40% of your question.

Here is the Mohsin Khan translation of these Ayah into English.

> **9:1**
>   Freedom from (all) obligations (is declared) from Allah and His Messenger (SAW) to those of the Mushrikun (polytheists, pagans, idolaters, disbelievers in the Oneness of Allah), with whom you made a treaty.
>
> **9:2**
>   So travel freely (O Mushrikun - see V.2:105) for four months (as you will) throughout the land, but know that you cannot escape (from the Punishment of) Allah, and Allah will disgrace the disbelievers.
>
> **9:3**
>   And a declaration from Allah and His Messenger to mankind on the greatest day (the 10th of Dhul-Hijjah - the 12th month of Islamic calendar) that Allah is free from (all) obligations to the Mushrikun (see V.2:105) and so is His Messenger. So if you (Mushrikun) repent, it is better for you, but if you turn away, then know that you cannot escape (from the Punishment of) Allah. And give tidings (O Muhammad SAW) of a painful torment to those who disbelieve.
>
> **9:4**
>   Except those of the Mushrikun with whom you have a treaty, and who have not subsequently failed you in aught, nor have supported anyone against you. So fulfill their treaty to them to the end of their term. Surely Allah loves Al- Mattaqun (the pious - see V.2:2).
>
> **9:5**
>   Then when the Sacred Months (the Ist, 7th, 11th, and 12th months of the Islamic calendar) have passed, then kill the Mushrikun (see V.2:105) wherever you find them, and capture them and besiege them, and prepare for them each and every ambush. But if they repent and perform As-Salat (Iqamat-as-Salat), and give Zakat, then leave their way free. Verily, Allah is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful.
>
> **9:6**
>   And if anyone of the Mushrikun (polytheists, idolaters, pagans, disbelievers in the Oneness of Allah) seeks your protection then grant him protection, so that he may hear the Word of Allah (the Quran), and then escort him to where he can be secure, that is because they are men who know not.
>
> **9:7**
>   How can there be a covenant with Allah and with His Messenger for the Mushrikun (polytheists, idolaters, pagans, disbelievers in the Oneness of Allah) except those with whom you made a covenant near Al-Masjid-al-Haram (at Makkah)? So long, as they are true to you, stand you true to them. Verily, Allah loves Al-Muttaqun (the pious - see V.2:2).
>
> **9:8**
>   How (can there be such a covenant with them) that when you are overpowered by them, they regard not the ties, either of kinship or of covenant with you? With (good words from) their mouths they please you, but their hearts are averse to you, and most of them are Fasiqun (rebellious, disobedient to Allah).
>
> **9:9**
>   They have purchased with the Ayat (proofs, evidences, verses, lessons, signs, revelations, etc.) of Allah a little gain, and they hindered men from His Way; evil indeed is that which they used to do.
>
> **9:10**
>   With regard to a believer, they respect not the ties, either of kinship or of covenant! It is they who are the transgressors.

As you can see in the verse 5 have mentioned to kill and I can't see it in two other translators.

Also in the verse 12 and 13 it's told again to kill and this time all of them escaped 'kill' from the translated text.

And all your named actions (kill-cheat-steal) any other kind is allowed to Muslims if it's [ Al-Qisas (the Law of Equality in punishment].