# Does every non-Muslim need to accept Islam or die?

Tags: quran, non-muslim, conversion

Is it correct that as per their holy book every human being on earth is "Kafir" (a person who rejected Islam) and need to accept Islam or die (not worth living).

Many counties in past and future going to be converted into 100% or in majority a Muslim nation.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Your question title is based on a wrong assumption, read the bible (especially the old testament) and you will be thought otherwise it is full of hatred against any non Jewish human being.

Comment: Our duty is to educate those that don't know about Islam.  We must share Islam with all of humanity.  There is no compulsion in accepting and embracing Islam  Our role is only to educate, share, and warn.

Answer (score 4):

Every kafir does not need to accept Islam or die.

On the contrary the life of a kafir is sacred and forbidden to take when one:

- has become the subject of the Islamic state by agreeing to pay the *[jizyah](https://sunnah.com/urn/406240)* tax.

  > قاتلوا ... حتى يعطوا الجزية
  >
  > Fight ... until they give the jizyah
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 9:29](https://quran.com/9/29)</sup>

  > وإذا لقيت عدوك من المشركين فادعهم إلى ثلاث خصال أو خلال فأيتهن ما أجابوك فاقبل منهم وكف عنهم ثم ادعهم إلى الإسلام ... فإن هم أبوا فسلهم الجزية فإن هم أجابوك فاقبل منهم وكف عنهم
  >
  > When you meet your enemies who are polytheists, invite them to three courses of action. If they respond to any one of these, you also accept it and withhold yourself from doing them any harm. Invite them to (accept) Islam; ... If they refuse to accept Islam, demand from them the Jizya. If they agree to pay, accept it from them and hold off your hands.
  >
  > <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/32/3)</sup>
- has a treaty with the Muslims

  > وإن جنحوا للسلم فاجنح لها وتوكل على الله
  >
  > And if they incline to peace, then incline to it [also] and rely upon Allah
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 8:61](https://quran.com/8/61)</sup>

  > من قتل معاهدا لم يرح رائحة الجنة وإن ريحها توجد من مسيرة أربعين عاما
  >
  > Whoever killed a person having a treaty with the Muslims, shall not smell the smell of Paradise though its smell is perceived from a distance of forty years.
  >
  > <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/58/8)</sup>
- has been granted *aman* (assurance of safety) by any Muslim

  > وإن أحد من المشركين استجارك فأجره حتى يسمع كلام الله ثم أبلغه مأمنه ذلك بأنهم قوم لا يعلمون
  >
  > And if any one of the polytheists seeks your protection, then grant him protection so that he may hear the words of Allah . Then deliver him to his place of safety. That is because they are a people who do not know.
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 9:6](https://quran.com/9/6)</sup>

  > ذمة المسلمين واحدة يسعى بها أدناهم
  >
  > The asylum granted by any Muslim is to be secured by all the Muslims, even if it is granted by one of the lowest social status among them
  >
  > <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/85/32) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/15/535)</sup>
- does not participate in fighting e.g. women, children, farmers, laborers, priests, disabled or elderly people etc.

  > وقاتلوا في سبيل الله الذين يقاتلونكم ولا تعتدوا إن الله لا يحب المعتدين
  >
  > Fight in the way of Allah those who fight you but do not transgress. Indeed. Allah does not like transgressors.
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 2:190](https://quran.com/2/190)</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure the "don't kill non-combatants" is as universally accepted as it may seem. In reliance of the travler section o9.10 it says "It is not permissible (A: in Jihad) to kill women or children unless they are fighting against the Muslims. Nor is it permissible to kill animals, unless they are being ridden into battle against the Muslims, or if killing them will help defeat the enemy. It is permissible to kill old men (0: old man (shaykh) meaning someone more than forty years of age) and monks.", which seems to indicate that killing those non-combatants is permissible.

Comment: @G.Bach My intent is to mention the majority view. Qurtubi in the Tafsir of 2:190 writes:  وللشافعي قولان : أحدهما : مثل قول الجماعة ، والثاني : يقتل هو والراهب ، والصحيح الأول لقول أبي بكر ليزيد ، ولا مخالف له فثبت أنه إجماع , according to him there are two sayings attributed to Imam Shafi regarding the elderly and monks, the first one is similar to view of the majority, that they will not be killed and the second is that they will be killed, and the correct one is the first one as it is proven from the instruction of Abu Bakr to Yazid, and no one opposed it so it is established by Ijmah.

Answer (score -1):

Every person on the earth, who is not a Muslim is a KAFIR, it is not true.

Meaning of KAFIR is considered wrongly by many people, let's first see it's meaning

disbeliever/unbeliever, faithless, apostate, atheist etc.

A person who don't know anything about God or Quran, he is not a KAFIR but those  after knowing the truth, reject to accept it those are KAFIR.

Uma, already gave enough proof that a person should not be killed but he would have to give the Jizia (tax) and he can live with them.

> Quran 8:55 Indeed, the worst of living creatures in the sight of Allah
>   are those who have disbelieved, and they will not [ever] believe