# Intolerance in muslims

Tags: history, muslim-practices, culture

If you read the question carefully I ask Intolerance in "Muslims" and not Islam. Islam is one of the most tolerant religions of all, but one thing that's oxymoron is intolerance in Muslim fanatics.

I have had a hard time dealing with Muslim clergies and orthodoxy big time. There is aggression and intolerance in them which is hard to counter. I believe this can be one of the seeds of all the ills of Muslim brotherhood that we witness at various places.

What is the reason it exists? Why are some of us so intolerant? Is their any historical or contemporary event/events responsible for it?

Comment: People as a whole have become intolerent (regardless of religion), I am not sure what's the reason for that. Maybe it would help if you search how do people become intolerant.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @mosaad Yes, true but then we should be more shielded from that. Abdul answer sheds a new light, its quite possible its work of shaitan.

Comment: that goes for all sorts of fanatics, not just the Muslim ones. many devout Muslims going thru the same thing as you do.

Comment: @AshwinSingh `Indeed, Allah does not wrong the people at all, but it is the people who are wronging themselves.` [quran yunus-44](http://quran.com/10/44)

Comment: I think this question should be protected.

Comment: You might find the answers to your questions from the book [Sword and Scimitar](https://www.raymondibrahim.com/2019/10/02/sword-scimitar-a-compelling-reminder-of-the-terrifying-dynamic-which-continues-to-drive-the-islamic-world/) by Raymond Ibrahim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well.. being a Muslim and living in a Muslim society, i agree with you totally on this matter! Muslims really have gone out of limits when it comes to anger management. The result can be seen in the world, how Muslims have developed themselves as barbaric savages. Not only in religious matters but also in every day issues.

Now coming towards the reasons, i think it's because of not following or being able to understand Islam. A big part is played in it by the Muslim Scholars and so called Molvis/Muftis! They preach the religion as an act of violence. Every Friday i go to mosque, i encounter their preaching of violence like We should attack Israel, kill the non-believers. Most of the times all they have to debate about is how only they are on the right track and every one else is astray and some even go to the limits saying that they are allowed to be killed and anyone who kills them will go to jannah (i have heard it with my own ears) which is total nonsense, whatever little Islam i have studied or know about is completely different from what they are preaching us. So for me, the ones who are guiding us towards the intolerance (Molvis, Muftis etc) are the biggest reason for this. They would come up with the false violent interpretation of almost anything. I am not saying that all of them are like that, there are plenty of preachers of peace as well in Islam but the violent intolerant ones out number them and they are poisoning the minds of Muslims.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what brother Abdul Jabbar has said, I would like to add some points I think is the cause of intolerance.

Quran is very clear that belief is a thing of heart and it is not to be forced on anyone. For example Quran says let there be no compulsion in religion (2:256) and don't force people on to Islam (10:99) etc. There are lot of similar verses in Quran that preaches tolerance. But the sad thing is some Muslims consider these verses as abrogated by what they call verse of sword that is 9:5. Actually 9:5 is a verse revealed during war and is not a command to kill all polytheists. This is clear from 9:6 where it is said if some polytheist seek refuge they should be taken to place of safety. If all polytheist should be killed why take them to a place of safety ?

So by considering lot of verses that commands tolerance as abrogated by citing an unrelated verse, these people say forcing people to Islam is allowed. You can see a question and answer in popular site IslamQA that states this http://islamqa.info/en/34770 . In this fatwa which is a question regarding 2:256, answers by quoting 9:5 and says "These and similar verses abrogate the verses which say that there is no compulsion to become Muslim. "

ISIS in iraq follow these type of interpretation that is why when they captured Sinjar, they gave only convert or leave option to Yazidi community there.

When Quran says even prophet(s.a) cannot make people he love accept Islam, these people say we can make people accept Islam by using force

> Indeed, [O Muhammad], you do not guide whom you like, but Allah guides
>   whom He wills. 28:56

Another problem in considering 2:256 which says "Let there be no compulsion in religion" as abrogated is, in the same verse it is saying "The right path has become clear from the wrong.". If the first part is abrogated then they would have to admit second part is also abrogated, which we know is not true.

You may be asking why non tolerant version is popular and tolerant version is minority. Non tolerant version will have upper hand because they will be using force to conquer lands and spreading their ideas and tolerant people would not go for war unless it is for self defense or for some genuine reason. This may explain why historically non tolerant version gets more popularity.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are not meant for argument and debate.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of Intolerance in Muslims is self Egoism and arrogance. Every One wants that other should listen to him It is present in most of the scholars and the satan is behind this means creating ego and arrogance in people. so that they will fight with each other.

And it is not only present in muslim but also in other religions but in muslims it is large because the Satan put his all efforts in muslims to put them in wrong path.